# Does a wait() waiting process consume system CPU

Tags: c++, c, linux, wait

**Question 1**

I want to develop a light deamon **`A`** which supervise another damemon **`B`**.
My light daemon **`A`** will run `wait()` in the whole time and check if the daemon **`B`** is still running every time the `wait()` return

Here after the source code of my light supervisor daemon **`A`**:

```
void main(void)
{
    int pid, status;
    while(1)
    {
        pid = wait(&status);
        if (!daemon_is_still_running("daemonB")) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}

int daemon_is_still_running(char *name)
{
    //this function check all the pid under the folder /proc and
    //return 0 in case the daemon is not running
    //return 1 in case the daemon is still running
}
```

Does the above code of my daemon **`A`** will cause a CPU load? Does the `wait()` function cause a CPU load ?

**Question 2**

Are there a way to detect if the daemon **`B`** is stopped with signal handlers?

Comment: `wait` is causing the process to sleep. The checks are performed by the scheduler which is running anyway. So no.

Comment: If you did not start daemon B then you cannot wait for it in A. wait is only for children and PTRACE subjects.

Comment: If you have 2 questions, ask 2 separate questions

Answer (score 2):

> Does the `wait()` function cause a CPU load ?

No, the `wait()` function does not consume any CPU while it is waiting.

But either your example is oversimplified, or it belies a misunderstanding of `wait()`'s behavior.  The `wait()` function is used to wait for *a child process* to *terminate or stop*, but your program does not spawn any children.  (Note that "terminate" and "stop" are different things.)  Moreover, if your program spawned the "daemon B" process it is monitoring, then it could tell from the returned pid and status whether that daemon was still running.

> Are there a way to detect if the daemon B is stopped with signal handlers?

When a process is stopped or terminated, a `SIGCHLD` is delivered to its parent process.  This interacts with `wait()`, but you can also register your own handler.  There is no built-in mechanism, however, for a process to register to be signaled when a process other than one of its own children stops or terminates.